# Expected array for frame error in zend2 framework

Tags: zend-framework2, php-7

I'm having a problem which only occurs on my live system. The system works with zend2 and PHP7. The problem is that my warning.log is flodded with following message:

> 2017-07-10T08:43:50+02:00 ERR: Expected array for frame X
>   {"Code":0,"File":"vendor/zendframework/zend-log/src/Formatter/Base.php","Line":105}

The X is a number between 0 and 25. At the end of these numerous errors I get another one:

> 2017-07-10T10:29:34+02:00 ERR: Unable to write
>   {"Code":0,"File":"vendor/zendframework/zend-log/src/Formatter/Base.php","Line":111}

I don't see a proper stack trace to see where this is coming from and I can't reprocude the problem on my local dev machine.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
A collegue told me that this error message comes from the C-level of PHP7. Has anyone an idea how to get a proper stack trace? Or what the problem could be?

I tried to catch the error with

```
...try{
    return (string) $value;
} catch(\Throwable $e){
    file_put_contents('error.txt',var_export($e,true),FILE_APPEND);
    file_put_contents('value.txt',var_export($value,true),FILE_APPEND);
    return (string) $value;
}
```

but it seems like this error could not be caught. This suggests that the information of my collegue is correct.

Comment: I got this error when PHP was unable to write a file into a specific dir. Is the directory which contains the log files writable for php?

Comment: Yes! Almost every directory in the project has every permission possible (777).

Comment: did `xdebug` enabled on your live system?

Comment: No xdebug is not running.

Answer (score 0):

An idea for your try/catch:

```
Zend\Stdlib\ErrorHandler::start(E_ALL);
$return = (string) $value;
$exception = Zend\Stdlib\ErrorHandler::stop();

file_put_contents('error.txt', var_export($exception, true), FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents('value.txt', var_export($value, true), FILE_APPEND);

return $return;
```

Comment: I tried the code above with a little change (`if($exception !== null)`) around the `file_put_contents` but so far the files are non existent. My guess is that this error cannot be caught cause it is "thrown" in the C-level of PHP.